# Laravel is too slow

Tags: php, laravel

I just set this page in the routing file `web.php`:

```
Route::get("/speedtest","SpeedController@speed_test");
```

Here is the speed test function:

```
public function speed_test(){
    return view("speedtest");
}
```

That returns `speedtest.blade.php` which contains just a `hello world`.

It takes between 2.5 s and 3.5 to load this page.

Other pages that use a middleware and some queries needs between 3.5 and 6.5 seconds. The database is almost empty and the queries returns just 3 or 4 items (something like `Files::where(user_id, Auth::user()->id)->get()` ).

So everything is slow, even empty sites. There is definitely something wrong.

The site is alone in a server with 4 GB RAM, SSD and 1 Gbit connection

Any help?

Comment: In all honesty, it sounds like a typical Laravel site to me.  It's a heavyweight framework.

Comment: Yes, if you want speed don't use it.

Comment: It's how it is.

Comment: Have you tried setting up xhprof or a similar profiling tool that gives feedback on how much time is spent in each function of the script execution?

Comment: Also, this guy makes it run faster by enabling cache and using PHP7 opcache https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/benchmarking-laravel-symfony-zend-2c01c2b270f8

Comment: Here's a reddit on the subject: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4qc3ck/laravel_performance_tuning/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Things to do to increase speed:

```
# Optimize the autoloading (very important!)
composer dumpautoload -o
# Cache the Laravel routes (very important on slower servers)
php artisan route:cache
php artisan api:cache
# Cache the core laravel configurations (including service providers, etc.)
php artisan config:cache
# Finally, tell Laravel to enable "production-ready optimizations."
#php artisan optimize # No longer needed/available in Laravel 5.6.
```

Run all that and report the time improvements!

You also, for best performance, make sure that Zend OPcache extension is installed and loaded (that's another question).

```
php -m
....
[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: It is now a fraction of what it used to be.